# How to add offline dictionary to Calibre?

Tags: offline, dictionary, ebooks, calibre

"I have recently installed calibre for ebook reading. To find the meaning of unknown words, the calibre has an option to look into the dictionary. I know to use an online dictionary with calibre. I want to use a rich offline dictionary with calibre."

I see there was no answer for this question by Posi2, and it would be very nice for linux users who have dict.org working offline. Does anybody know how to configure Calibre to use it?

Comment: If any other ebook application provide such facility please, suggest.

Comment: I can't work out what is 'rich offline'?

Comment: Thanks, now I get your meaning. Looks like it can be done but you will need to install a dictionary server...

Comment: How I can add it to calibre? Thanks